# firebase Deploy issue with angular 16

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I try to deploy my project to firebase it come with this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cerEe.png)

I try to research from internet and nothing successful run base on the angular 16, has anyone successfully do this with the newest version of angular?

if yes, please help me to the steps with that, thanks.

I try to fix the dist destination inside the firebase.json, not work

Comment: Could you paste your firebase.json configuration?

Comment: what happens when you try?  Do you get an error somewhere?  Does it complete but the project folder is empty on firebase?  What steps are you following to deploy it?

Comment: here is my firebase.json@JensonRaby:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/shop-demo",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: I use the official steps as below:
1. ng build
2. login firebase
3. firebase init
4.chose the destination folder in dist
5 deploy

I do not think I done wrong, but I think it would have a special step for the angular config but I can not find in internet